# Creating associations for subscription-based model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models. These are the `User`, `Product` and `Price` model. I want `Users` to be able to subscribe to `Products` and watch the `Price` model for lower prices. I'm thinking about how to set this up but haven't figured out the correct associations.

My associations as of now are like this:

*Note: Many fields (table columns as well) have been erased for simplicity*

```
class User
  has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :prices
end

class Product
  # table columns - :name
  has_many :prices
  has_many :users, :through => :prices
end

class Price 
  # table columns - :cost, :user_id, :product_id, :store_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store
end
```

I was going to set this up by making a boolean in the `Product` model called `:watch_product` but I get stuck at the associations. Should I give `Product` a `user_id` or the other way around? I have a `:through` association but no `user_id` on `Product` or a `product_id` on `User`.  Should the `watch_product` go on the `Price` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not store the user information in the `Price` model. I would introduce a separate model for storing user to product subscription.

```
class User
  has_many :user_products
  has_many :products, :through => :user_products
  has_many :prices, :through => :products 
end

class UserProduct
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  has_many :prices
  has_many :user_products
  has_many :users, :through => :user_products
end

class Price 
  # table columns - :cost, :product_id, :store_id
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store

  scope :by_product, lambda {|product| where(:product_id => product)}
  scope :by_store, lambda {|store| where(:store_id => store)}
end
```

Now you can get the prices for user as follows:

```
user.prices.by_product(12)
user.prices.by_store(10)
user.prices.by_product(12).by_store(10)
```

Comment: What would you do with the `:watch_price` field?

Comment: Adding a row in the UserProduct table is equivalent to watching a product. E.g: `user.products << product` will add the products to watch.